# Temporary storage for collecting data prior to sending

Tags: php, concurrency, storage, monitoring

I'm working on a composer package for PHP apps. The goal is to send some data after requests, queue jobs, other actions that are taken. My initial (and working) idea is to use `register_shutdown_function` to do it. There are a couple of issues with this approach, firstly, this increases the page response time, meaning that there's the overhead of computing the request, plus sending the data via my API. Another issue is that long-running processes, such as queue workers, do not execute this method for a long time, therefore there might be massive gaps between when the data was created and when it's sent and processed.

My thought is that I could use some sort of temporary storage to store the data and have a cronjob to send it every minute. The only issue I can see with this approach is managing concurrency on hight IO. Because many processes will be writing to the file every (n) ms, there's an issue with reading the file and removing lines that had been already sent.

Another option which I'm trying to desperately avoid is using the client database. This could potentially cause performance issues.

What would be the preferred way to do this?

Edit: the package is essentially a monitoring agent.

Comment: This is where RabbitMQ and the like would solve this problem quite elegantly.

Comment: It does not. This is a composer package which should not depend on client infrastructure.

Comment: Hm alright. Then is it a requirement that every request writes to the same file? If not, make each write to a unique file and process these in batch with the cronjob. This should prevent concurrency issues.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but on a high load system it would generate thousands of files which just seems like a very messy solution, though it might be a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**There are a couple of issues with this approach, firstly, this increases the page response time, meaning that there's the overhead of computing the request, plus sending the data via my API**

I'm not sure you can get around this, there will be additional overhead to doing more work within the context of a web request.  I feel like using a job-queue based/asynchronous system is minimizing this for the client.  Whether you choose a local file system write, or a socket write you'll have that extra overhead, but you'll be able to return to the client immediately and not block on the processing of that request.

**Another issue is that long-running processes, such as queue workers, do not execute this method for a long time, therefore there might be massive gaps between when the data was created and when it's sent and processed.**

Isn't this the whole point?? :p To return to your client immediately, and then asynchronously complete the job at some point in the future? Using a job queue allows you to decouple and scale your worker pool and webserver separately.  Your webservers can be pretty lean because heavy lifting is deferred to the workers.

**My thought is that I could use some sort of temporary storage to store the data and have a cronjob to send it every minute.**

I would def recommend looking at a job queue opposed to rolling your own.  This is pretty much solved and there are many extremely popular open source projects to handle this (any of the MQs) Will the minute cron job be doing the computation for the client? How do you scale that? If a file has 1000 entries, or you scale 10x and has 10000 will you be able to do all those computations in less than a minute? What happens if a server dies? How do you recover? Inter-process concurrency? Will you need to manage locks for each process? Will you use a separate file for each process and each minute? To bucket events? What happens if you want less than 1 minute runs?

**Durability Guarantees**

What sort of guarantees are you offering your clients?  If a request returns can the client be sure that the job is persisted and it will be completed at sometime in the future?

---

I would def recommend choosing a worker queue, and having your webserver processes write to it.  It's an extremely popular problem with so many resources on how to scale it, and with clear durability and performance guarantees.

[image]

Comment: Essentially my package is a monitoring agent. I don't see how my clients would wan't to install, manage and maintain MQ software that has nothing to do with their applications. That's the main issue here. I appreciate your answer but it does not solve my problem :/

Comment: Are your clients going to register cron and maintain/monitor it? Are they going to take care of monitoring the background job count, success, resources? Is there any way you could leverage an already made monitoring agent?? statsd, collectd, fluentd, etc?  You asked for the preferred way, and I would def recommend leverage extremely popular architecture, that is well studied, has lots of excellent battle tested, well documented, services, with thriving communities, opposed to a homegrown solution

Comment: The cron is registered on the client application and is fired as a sub-process by the main CLI script that's built into the framework I'm targeting (laravel). I've decided to implement 4 storage engines for the users to pick: memory (send data after request has been served to the client via `fastcgi_finish_request` if available), database, file and one of your suggested agents. Which one of the 3 you mentioned would be best for JSON collection? I'm just trying to avoid integration complexity even at the cost of performance. I'm building an MVP so I kind of need to test the idea first:)

Comment: By the way, thank you for pushing me in the right direction:)